# Self join data varying SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, self-join

I have a table `Employee` which contains the name along with manager id so I am using a self join to find the manager of the employee.

My table structure and table data:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    ManagerID INT
)

INSERT INTO Employee
    SELECT 1, 'Mike', 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'David', 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Roger', NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Mary', 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'Joseph',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'Ben',2
```

Selecting all data

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
```

Output is:

[image]

Now when I use this query:

```
 SELECT e1.Name, e2.NAME AS 'mngrname'
 FROM Employee e1
 INNER JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.EmployeeID = e2.ManagerID
```

I get the data as:

[image]

Now when I change the query to:

```
SELECT e1.Name, e2.NAME AS 'mngrname'
FROM Employee e1
INNER JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmployeeID
```

The output is:

[image]

The question; why is it happening? Why does the data change?

Comment: Because it's a different query. It makes complete sense - I'm not sure what there is to misunderstand here

Comment: Why do you think it should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.Name, e2.NAME AS 'mngrname'
 FROM Employee e1
 INNER JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.EmployeeID = e2.ManagerID
```

Here you are finding `e1's manager`.In join since both table are same so it is Self join.In this join alias `e1` is `Employee` table and `e2` is `manager` table.

So `e1.Name` is `Employee name` and `e2.Name` is `manager`

Now you can also make alias e1 as manager table and alias e2 as employee table.
In this case they will produce same result but column name will hold different information.

```
SELECT e1.Name, e2.NAME AS 'mngrname'
FROM Employee e1
INNER JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.ManagerID = e2.EmployeeID
```

Here e1 is manager table and e2 is employee table.

So `e1.Name` is `manager name` and `e2.Name` is `Employee`